# Why I am getting this error after executing 'symfony doctrine:database:create'

Tags: php, symfony, web, frameworks, symfony6

Help! I get this

> error: "Uncaught Error:Class "Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle" not found".

After executing Symfony `doctrine:database:create`, I don't know where it comes from, and it's blocking me from continuing! I am using Symfony 6

Comment: If you created your app with something like `symfony new --full app` then the monolog bundles would have been installed automatically.  If not then you need to install it with `composer require symfony/monolog-bundle`. This is very basic stuff.

Comment: I didn't create the project myself,, symfony is new to me so don't know how it works, thank you any way

Comment: The monolog bundle configures a logger for Symfony.  For whatever reason the vendor code for it does not seem to be installed.  Hard to say why.  It might help to go ahead and just create a new app with the command I showed.  That would at least give you an idea of what a working app looks like.